# WebView Text Selection

Tags: android, webview

I want to achieve something like this  -- text selection plus custom actions ..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iwmG43D0vD4

I have done sufficient research on this topic and concluded that webview text selection and overriding it functionality is not possible ..

Seems that webview's functionality is very limited atleast in the case of text manipulation.

I had decent success by accessing webview's private nativeGetSelection method ( i was able to get selected text ).. but still i was unable to suppress the default dialog box .. and using private methods dosen't seem to be a safe action tooo ..

I was about to scrap my thought of doing that project .. then i came to see that default web browser provides good text selection capability and further provides custom quick action to manipulate the text .. I am really confused at this point ....

can anyone .. with all their expertise ... point out how to achieve that behavior .. ?

what view does google docs app use to achieve that behavior .. ?

Comment: Hey @Sakti, how did you manage to get the selected text in a webView?

Comment: Use this view https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection. It worked for me..  .. Its from the answer below .. You can build this project to see it working ..

Comment: In fact, I just need the selected text, nothing else. How did you use the nativeGetSelection method for that purpose? Is it still available in Android 4.1?

Comment: I accessed private methods using 'java reflections'.. in emulator it worked fine .. but in device it ran on one and in other it gave error. And btw private methods are subject to change without notice. In 4.1 i was not able to see that method, i guess its no more .. You can use the below stated method to select text as it uses javascript to select text and blocks default actions ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got something similar working in 2.2 - 4.0.3. I used a javascript interface and passed all touches to it. Of course to do that you'll need enough control over the web content to include the javascript file. I have this solution in an app in production and I've put an example project on github. The github project includes the necessary js in the assets folder as well as a test page and web view that loads the test page and implements all necessary methods to handle the selection. The link to the github project is https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection. Have at it.

Comment: Hey thanks btate .. i believe this solution works best for my use case .. ;)

Comment: @btate That github project is great, however its not working on Tablet with ON version  - 4.1.2.

Comment: Guys anybody have tested this project with OS version 4.1.2 ? For me its not working.

Comment: how to open custom dialog when text selection done in webview ?